How to organize sellers and buyers in a SQL query, or remove duplicates or aggregate rows?
I have this SQL statement:
SELECT
    Datos_Propiedad,
    Datos_Primer_Vendedor AS Datos_Primer_Vendedor,
    Datos_Primer_Comprador AS Datos_Primer_Comprador,
    Datos_Segundo_Vendedor AS Datos_Segundo_Vendedor,
    Datos_Segundo_Comprador AS Datos_Segundo_Comprador
FROM (
    SELECT
        CASE
            WHEN v.Placa IS NOT NULL THEN
                CONCAT('Vehículo: ', v.marca, ' ', v.modelo, ', Placa: ', v.Placa)
            WHEN i.Direccion_exacta IS NOT NULL THEN
                CONCAT('Inmueble: ', i.Tipo, ', Dirección: ', i.Direccion_exacta)
        END AS Datos_Propiedad,
        CONCAT(p1.primer_nombre, ' ', p1.primer_apellido) AS Datos_Primer_Vendedor,
        CONCAT(p2.primer_nombre, ' ', p2.primer_apellido) AS Datos_Primer_Comprador,
        CONCAT(p3.primer_nombre, ' ', p3.primer_apellido) AS Datos_Segundo_Vendedor,
        CONCAT(p4.primer_nombre, ' ', p4.primer_apellido) AS Datos_Segundo_Comprador
    FROM documento d
    LEFT JOIN vehiculo v ON d.Placa = v.Placa
    LEFT JOIN inmueble i ON d.Direccion_exacta = i.Direccion_exacta
    JOIN registrada r1 ON d.Folio_inicial = r1.Folio_inicial AND d.Numero_libro = r1.Numero_libro
    JOIN persona p1 ON r1.DNI_NIE = p1.DNI_NIE
    JOIN tipopersona tp1 ON r1.ID_TipoPersona = tp1.ID_TipoPersona AND tp1.nombre_TipoPersona = 'Vendedor'
    JOIN registrada r2 ON d.Folio_inicial = r2.Folio_inicial AND d.Numero_libro = r2.Numero_libro
    JOIN persona p2 ON r2.DNI_NIE = p2.DNI_NIE
    JOIN tipopersona tp2 ON r2.ID_TipoPersona = tp2.ID_TipoPersona AND tp2.nombre_TipoPersona = 'Comprador'
    JOIN registrada r3 ON d.Folio_inicial = r3.Folio_inicial AND d.Numero_libro = r3.Numero_libro
    JOIN persona p3 ON r3.DNI_NIE = p3.DNI_NIE
    JOIN tipopersona tp3 ON r3.ID_TipoPersona = tp3.ID_TipoPersona AND tp3.nombre_TipoPersona = 'Vendedor'
    JOIN registrada r4 ON d.Folio_inicial = r4.Folio_inicial AND d.Numero_libro = r4.Numero_libro
    JOIN persona p4 ON r4.DNI_NIE = p4.DNI_NIE
    JOIN tipopersona tp4 ON r4.ID_TipoPersona = tp4.ID_TipoPersona AND tp4.nombre_TipoPersona = 'Comprador'
    WHERE (d.Placa IN (
        SELECT Placa FROM documento
        GROUP BY Placa
        HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2
    ) OR d.Direccion_exacta IN (
        SELECT Direccion_exacta FROM documento
        GROUP BY Direccion_exacta
        HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2
    )) 
) AS resultados;

This is what I got from its execution:

But I want this result:

What MySQL functions could help me obtain a result like that?
What I basically need is two rows with two buyers and two sellers. I think there must be a aggregation or subquery to obtain something what I'm showing in the second image.
